# How to connect to postgres user on macOS

Tags: postgresql

In the past I am reasonably confident that I had used a `postgres` user on macOS. However I do not see it on the brew-installed version on my `catalina` laptop:

```
sudo -u postgres
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Did I miss some step? I *am* able to view multiple databases on that laptop:

```
aact2=# \l
                               List of databases
    Name    | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges
------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 aact       | steve | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 aact1      | steve | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 aact2      | steve | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 aactold    | steve | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres   | steve | UTF8     | C           | C           |
 template0  | steve | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/steve         +
            |       |          |             |             | steve=CTc/steve
 template1  | steve | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/steve         +
            |       |          |             |             | steve=CTc/steve
(10 rows)
```

What steps do I need to perform to have an accessible `postgres` database superuser?

**Update** Here is the output from `\du`

```
aact2=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 bluej     |                                                            | {}
 steve     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

**Another update**  @AdrianKlaver suspected that the `steve` user were the superuser -and apparently he is correct

```
aact2=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 bluej     |                                                            | {}
 steve     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

The reason I did not believe that `steve` were the superuser is that `create role` had failed with a permission error.  I will have to go back and see why that failed in that way as a separate task.

Comment: What does \l template1 show? Also \du?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  I did not show all db's for confidentiality - but now have included the template's and the `template1` is there : see updated OP.    I also just included `\du`

Comment: So it looks like the Postgres instance was installed with ```steve``` as the superuser. I'm guessing there is no ```postgres``` system user. I'm not a Mac user, but I did find these commands for listing system users: ```dscl . list /Users``` and to filter out daemon/process accounts ```dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'```

Comment: I had tried that first - when logged in as `steve` . I had not been able to create a new role due to permissions. But now I looked and that should be possible. Pls make an answer and I will award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. One, there is no system user postgres. Two, the Postgres cluster was created(`initdb`) as user `steve` so the `superuser` for the cluster is `steve`, as by default `initdb` uses the user name of the system user running it. FYI that can be changed at init by doing:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html

```
-U username
--username=username

    Selects the user name of the database superuser. This defaults to the name of the effective user running initdb. It is really not important what the superuser's name is, but one might choose to keep the customary name postgres, even if the operating system user's name is different.
```

In any case it really does not matter as long as you know who the `superuser` is.